# Ruby Version 2.3.3 Gemfile 2.3.0 (Sprockets Update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm a newbie at Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to update the Gem file but it keeps giving me this error.

> Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0

[image: Error1]

The reason I'm trying to update the gem file is because of a security vulnerability .

[image: Error 2]

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory... What exactly is your question? If you want to upgrade the ruby version to `2.3.3`, then update the `Gemfile`?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails-4`? Which version are you actually using? (Is it actually `v5.x`?)

Answer (score 1):

check your gemfile, there will be

```
ruby '2.3.0'
```

you need to change it to

```
ruby '2.3.3'
```

more you can read here https://bundler.io/v1.12/gemfile_ruby.html and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Answer (score 0):

Just change your ruby version at gem file to the version suggested by the error. Let's see if this works